# Length of predicted values is not equal to actual values. keras TPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tpu

When I try to predict I got either length shorter or larger than the actual value.
What should I do. Actual length is 700.

I got 704 from following way
`y_val=model.predict(val_dataset,steps=(len(val_label)/BATCH_SIZE))`

I got 672 using following way
`y_val=model.predict(val_dataset,steps=(len(val_label)//BATCH_SIZE))`

What should I do get it equal to 700.
`len(val_label)` is 700
BATCH_SIZE is 32

Comment: try BATCH_SIZE of 35

Comment: in. TPU batch size is calculated this way.
`BATCH_SIZE = 4*strategy.num_replicas_in_sync`
So I don't think I can make it 35

Comment: just tried a simple model with batch_size of 35 on TPU - it works. You probably mean recommended batch size

Comment: It might be related to [tpu-predict-method-has-the-wrong-shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62379562/output-of-keras-predict-method-has-the-wrong-shape-when-using-google-colabs-tpu). Can you try to latest version of tensorflow 2.3.1 or [tf-nightly](https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly)

Comment: @Andrey solution produce NaN loss, i will try Gagik solution if it works